# The code shows that a list of strings contains a particular word. Please tell me why my code is not giving the right answer?

Tags: python, string, list, search, list-comprehension

def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

```
Example:
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
>>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
>>> [0]
"""

for i,doc in enumerate(doc_list):
    l=[i for j in doc.split() if j.rstrip('.,').lower()==keyword.lower()]

return l
```

Comment: What is the word_search function? Your code isn't written properly, please post your code again here (edit your question)

Comment: The list comprehension creates a new list for each time the for loop is iterated. You probably want to append the list.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return you the list with indexes of items that the keyword in the string item.

```
doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    return [i for i, v in enumerate(doc_list) if v.lower().find(keyword.lower()) > -1]
word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
```

return indexes

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: This will return the index for Casinoville as well, and might not be what @leo arad wants

Comment: In the example, the function returned [0] and it wasn't the desired behavior so probably there is a need for getting "Casinoville" value index as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
   l=[]
   for i,doc in enumerate(doc_list):
       l.append([i for j in doc.split() if j.rstrip('.,').lower()==keyword.lower()])
   return l

doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
match=word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
print(match)
```

The search will not return the index for Casinoville, as it is not a separate word